# Changing the state (the pieces on the board) of a chess game

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a Chess Game, I'm stuck with this:

I create a bunch of panels each one has a label that has an icon (piece icon) with a loop for every panel to represent a case in the game. How can I delete an icon from the last position after the user drags the piece to a new position?

```
import ma.jerroudi.cheesegame.bouard.Bouard;
import ma.jerroudi.cheesegame.bouard.Case;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class CheeseGameGui extends JFrame {
    Point prevPt;
    Point currentPt;

    public CheeseGameGui() {
        Bouard bouard = new Bouard();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent eP) {
                prevPt = eP.getPoint();
                System.out.println(" x: " + eP.getX() + " y: " + eP.getY());
                System.out.println("tab[" + (int) prevPt.getX() / 50 + "] [" + (int) prevPt.getY() / 50 + "]");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent eR) {
                currentPt = eR.getPoint();
                System.out.println(" x: " + eR.getX() + " y: " + eR.getY());
                bouard.caseChange((int) prevPt.getY() / 50, (int) prevPt.getX() / 50, (int) currentPt.getY() / 50, (int) currentPt.getX() / 50);
                System.out.println("piece name : " + bouard.getCase((int) currentPt.getY() / 50, (int) currentPt.getX() / 50).getSymbol());
            }
        });
        this.setTitle("jeroudi cheese game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
        this.setIconImage(image.getImage());
        for (int i = 0; i <= Bouard.MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= Bouard.MAX_SIZE; j++) {
                JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
                this.add(mypanel);
                JLabel labelImg = new JLabel();
                int xIndice = j * 50;
                int yIndice = i * 50;
                mypanel.setBounds(xIndice, yIndice, 50, 50);
                mypanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));
                ImageIcon pieceImg = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(bouard.getCase(i, j).getPiecePhat()).getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                labelImg.setIcon(pieceImg);
                mypanel.add(labelImg);
                this.getContentPane().add(mypanel);
            }
        }
        setSize(450, 450);
        setLayout(null);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811247/drawing-in-jlayeredpane-over-exising-jpanels/6811800#6811800 for one approach.

Comment: [One more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-swing-chess-gui) approach

Comment: And just to completely screw with you, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621830/jlayeredpanel-layout-manager-free-moving-objects/26624184#26624184), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836723/which-layout-manager-to-use-on-this-game/41837799#41837799) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698217/how-to-make-draggable-components-with-imageicon/13700490#13700490)

Answer (score 1):

`setLayout(null);` Don't do this. Instead, set a `GridLayout` to the chessboard (a single `JPanel`).

Don't add labels to panels then add the panels to the chessboard, simply add the 'labels' directly to the one chessboard panel. But make them undecorated buttons (`JButton`).

---

### Important

Keep a reference to the buttons in an array (`JButton[8][8]`).

Establish a `ChessModel` which encapsulates the state of a chess game and a method to configure the GUI (the button icons) to match the model.

When the user (or their opponent) moves a piece, update the model then refresh the chessboard.

---

Oh, and now the GUI is laid out, instead of the (wrong) guess `setSize(450, 450);`, simply call `pack()` for the right sized GUI. For more on laying out the chessboard, see [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).