# How to implement drag-and-drop and piece movement on a chess board in Java (repaint() doesn't work)?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a chess project in Java using Java Swing for the graphical interface. I have a Board class that extends JPanel, where I draw the chessboard and the pieces, and I've implemented mouse interaction to be able to move the pieces on the board.

My problem is that I'm having trouble implementing drag-and-drop and proper piece movement on the board. I've tried using MouseMotionListener and MouseListener to detect drag-and-drop events, but it doesn't seem to work correctly because i don't see any moves.The coordinates are updating, but the image is not.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
  public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private final PieceRender pieceRender = new PieceRender();
    private final int cellSize = 600 / 8;
    private final int initialX = 45;
    private final int initialY = 55;
    private Point movingPiece;
    private int pieceLocationIndex;

    public Board() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawBoard(g2);
        drawLabel(g2);

        pieceRender.pieceByDefault(g2,initialX,initialY,cellSize);

    }

    private void drawBoard(Graphics2D g2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                drawSquare(g2,2 * j, 2 * i, true);
                drawSquare(g2,1 + 2 * j, 1 + 2 * i, true);

                drawSquare(g2,1 + 2 * j, 2 * i, false);
                drawSquare(g2,2 * j, 1+ 2 * i, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawSquare(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, boolean color){
        g.setColor(color ? Color.WHITE : Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(initialX + x * cellSize, initialY + y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    private void drawLabel(Graphics2D g2){
        char[] litere = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};
        char[] cifre = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};

        Font font = new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 20);
        g2.setFont(font);

        var pozitionX = initialX;
        var pozitionY = initialY;

        for(int i = 0; i < litere.length; i++){
            g2.drawChars(litere, i, 1, pozitionX + 30, pozitionY - 10);
            pozitionX += 75;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < cifre.length; i++){
            g2.drawChars(cifre, i, 1, pozitionX - 625, pozitionY + 45);
            pozitionY += 75;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        var actualX = (e.getPoint().x - initialX) / cellSize;
        var actualY = (e.getPoint().y - initialY) / cellSize;

        for (int i = 0; i < pieceRender.piecesBox.size(); i++) {
            if (pieceRender.piecesBox.get(i).getCoordinates().getPos_X() == actualX
                   && pieceRender.piecesBox.get(i).getCoordinates().getPos_Y() == actualY){
                    pieceLocationIndex = i;
           }else System.out.println("Nui");

        }
        System.out.println("Coord: " + actualX);
        System.out.println("Coord: " + actualY);
        movingPiece = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        var actualX = (e.getPoint().x - initialX) / cellSize;
        var actualY = (e.getPoint().y - initialY) / cellSize;

        pieceRender.piecesBox.get(pieceLocationIndex).getCoordinates().setPos_X(actualX);
        pieceRender.piecesBox.get(pieceLocationIndex).getCoordinates().setPos_Y(actualY);

        movingPiece = null;
        System.out.println("Coord " + pieceRender.piecesBox.get(pieceLocationIndex).getCoordinates().getPos_X());
        System.out.println("Coord " + pieceRender.piecesBox.get(pieceLocationIndex).getCoordinates().getPos_Y());
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        movingPiece = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            Board board = new Board();

            board.addMouseListener(board);
            board.addMouseMotionListener(board);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess Game");
            frame.add(board);
            frame.setSize(800, 800);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        });

        t1.start();

    }
}
```

And draw them with this method:

```
 public void pieceByDefault (Graphics2D g2, int initialX, int initialY, int cellSize) {
        PieceFactory pieceFactory = new PieceFactory();

        char[][] defaultPositions = {
                {'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R'},
                {'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'},
                {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
                {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
                {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
                {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
                {'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'},
                {'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r'}
        };

        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                char pieceType = defaultPositions[y][x];
                if (pieceType != ' ') {
                    ChessPiece piece = pieceFactory.create(pieceType, new Coordinates(x, y));
                    piecesBox.add(piece);
                    drawPiece(g2, piece.getIndex(), piece
                     .getCoordinates().getPos_X(), piece.getCoordinates()
                     .getPos_Y(),initialX, initialY, cellSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }

 public void drawPiece(Graphics2D g2, int index, 
     int initialX, int initialY,int primeX, int primeY, int  cellSize){
        drawImage(g2, index, initialX, initialY,primeX, primeY, cellSize);
    }
```

Comment: You don't show the code there you are connecting the adapters.

Comment: Now, here's the full code. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698217/how-to-make-draggable-components-with-imageicon/13700490#13700490); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621830/jlayeredpanel-layout-manager-free-moving-objects/26624184#26624184)